# Finding limit of a sequence defined by another sequence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

> Let there be $\{a_n\}$ such that $a_{n+2}=2a_{n+1}+2a_n$ and $\{b_n\}$ such that $b_n=\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ if $\lim_{n \to \infty}b_n=L$ what is the limit $L$?

I thought about if $L$ exist so I can use the arithmetic laws of limits.

$\lim b_n=\lim \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$  and $\lim b_n=\lim \frac{2a_{n+1}+a_n}{a_{n+1}}$.

But could not find how to proceed to find the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From $a_{n+2} = 2 a_{n+1} + 2 a_n$ it follows that
$b_{n+1} = 2 + 2/b_n$. If $\lim_{n \to \infty} b_n = L$ exists,
what can you conclude about $L$?

Comment: I get $L_1=1-\sqrt{3},$ ,$L_2=1+\sqrt{3}$ can they be both?

Comment: Both are used in a formula for $a_n$. As in every forward power iteration, the quotient converges to the larger of the two (largest of all eigenvalues), $L_2$, with a geometric rate of $L_1/L_2$.

Comment: @gbox: Can the limit of $(b_n)$ be negative?

Comment: @MartinR no because $a_{n+1}>a_n$ therefore$ \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}>0$?

Comment: @LutzL sorry, I did not understand the explanation

Comment: @gbox: Yes. So you can exclude one of the solutions of the quadratic equation.

Comment: You get this special result by following the answer of Michael, $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{Aλ^{n+1}+Bμ^{n+1}}{Aλ^n+Bμ^n}$. You get the general interpretation by writing the recursion in matrix form for the vectors $\binom{a_n}{a_{n-1}}$.

Answer (score 1):

First solve the recursion for $a_n$.    The general solution is 
$a_n=A\lambda^n+B\mu^n$.  Use the recursion to find a formula that $\lambda$ and $\mu$ satisfy; then calculate $b_n$.